# Grails findWhere, using a map as the parameter is not working

Tags: grails, dictionary, parameters

I'm still using Grails 1.3.7, and I got a query using like:

```
def paramsMap = ['columnA':'xxx','columnB':'xxx','columnC':'xxx']
def invitations = UserInvitation.findAllWhere(paramsMap)
```

I got nothing, but is I use it like this:

```
def invitations = UserInvitation.findAllWhere(['columnA':'xxx','columnB':'xxx','columnC':'xxx'])
```

Well, I could got what as I expected.

This is really confusing me, can anybody help me to figure out what's the difference?

Comment: mind show the actual code, there might be a typo you missed or the map doesn't have the contents you expect?

Comment: Thanks, @getbuckts , u'r right, after recheck the value I put into the map, it doesn't have the value I expect.